# Cannot pass asterisk character to external command via powershell

Tags: powershell

I cannot pass an asterisk character to external command using powershell

I use following a line like

```
& .\args.bat @("-arg1", "-arg2", "*.test.com")
```

where args.bat just dumps passed arguments

```
@ECHO off
ECHO The %~nx0 script args are...
for %%I IN (%*) DO ECHO %%I
```

And instead of passing "*.test.com" it lookups up current directory for files matching pattern "*.test.com" and sends list of them to args.bat

That can be seen if you use "*" instead of "*.test.com"

I've also tried back tick character to escape asterisk, but it didn't help

In my case using asterisk is required as I'm passing it to makecert.exe to create wildcard domain certificate

Please help

Comment: Remove `ECHO off` and you will see which commands executed by `.bat` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing that.  As a test I created args.bat like so:

```
'pause' > args.bat
```

Then executed it:

```
& .\args.bat @("-arg1", "-arg2", "*.ps1")
```

When I look in task manager at the command line for that cmd.exe, I see:

[image]

It must be something the batch file is doing because PowerShell is doing nothing to your `*`.  BTW I used `*.ps1` because the directory I executed from had a ton of ps1 files in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are PS 3.0 or higher you can use "stop parsing operator" `--%`. See `help about_parsing` for details.